# Event never firing?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to add some event listener to `document`, but for some reason it looks like the `click` event is never fired, because the callback is never called:

```
function NotJquery(element) {
    this.element = element;

    return this;
}

NotJquery.prototype.eventFired = function(event, callback) {
    console.log('in NotJquery prototype');
    return function (event, callback) {
        element.addEventListener(event, callback, true);
    };
};
    
var $ = function(element) {
    return new NotJquery(element);
};

function Test() {
}
    
Test.prototype.addListener = function() {
    console.log('in Test prototype');
    $(document).eventFired('click', function() {
        console.log('click event fired');
    });
};

(function() {
    var test= new Test();
    test.addListener();
}());
```

Both the messages: "in Test prototype" and "in NotJquery prototype" are logged in the console, but when I click somewhere in my document the message "click event fired" is not output in the console. I do not see what is wrong with my code. Anybody has an idea to get it working?

http://jsfiddle.net/Nn3tZ/1/

Comment: The `eventFired` method does not take any arguments, yet you are passing it 2

Comment: Sorry. My mistake, but even with that fixed it still doesn't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is expecting something like this:

```
NotJquery.prototype.eventFired = function(event, callback) {
    this.element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn3tZ/2/

Answer (score 1):

`element` is not defined within your `eventFired` function (but that's not the only problem). Here's a minimal update:

```
NotJquery.prototype.eventFired = function(event, callback) {
    var self = this; // <== Change 1 of 2

    console.log('in NotJquery prototype');
    return function () {
        self.element.addEventListener(event, callback, true);
    //  ^-- Change 2 of 2
    };
};
```

Unlike some other languages (Java, C#), `this` is **not optional** when referring to a property on the current object. Separately, the function you're creating within `eventFired` won't have the right `this`, so that's why I've stowed it away as `self` and then used `self` within the generated function (which is a *closure*).

Separately, you're passing `event` and `callback` into `eventFired` but then *also* declaring them on the generated function (it's not at all clear to me why you're generating a function there at all), so the ones you pass into `eventFired` are never used.

More reading *(on my anemic blog)*:

- [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: With this, the client code would need to be `$(document).eventFired('click', function() {
        console.log('click event fired');
    })();`, which doesn't make any sense ;P

Comment: @Esailija: The code's pretty messed up, I flagged up a couple of issues but really it needs a rewrite.

Comment: @user6669: Sorry, that came out rather more harsh than it was intended to. I would recommend continuing experimenting with things, and doing a lot of reading up on techniques and how JavaScript works. Good luck with it.